# Plist not loading?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Im building a super simple app, just for practice and I can't seem to get the plist file to load when the app starts up. I am using a utility app template and below is some of my code.

This is where I am trying to load the data, and if there is no path to plist then create one:

```
-(void) loadData
{
// load data here
NSString *dataPath = [self getFilePath];
BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataPath];

NSLog(@"Does the file exist? %i", fileExists);
// if there is data saved load it into the person array, if not let's create the array to use
if (fileExists) {
    NSLog(@"There is already and array so lets use that one");
    personArray= [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:dataPath];
    NSLog(@"The number of items in the personArray %i", personArray.count);
    arrayNumber.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",personArray.count];
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"There is no array so lets create one");
    personArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    arrayNumber.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",personArray.count];
}
}
```

Here is where I have a mutable array and then trying to add it to the plist.
    // add the person object to the array
        [personArray addObject:personObject];

```
    for (Person *obj in personArray)
    {
        NSLog(@"obj: %@", obj);
        NSLog(@"obj.firstName: %@", obj.firstName);
        NSLog(@"obj.lastName: %@", obj.lastName);
        NSLog(@"obj.email: %@", obj.email);
    }


    // check the count of the array to make sure it was added
    NSLog(@"Count of the personArray is %i", personArray.count);
    arrayNumber.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",personArray.count];

    // check to see if the object was added
    NSLog(@"The number of items in the personArray %i", personArray.count);
    [personArray writeToFile:[self getFilePath] atomically:YES];
```

Everything seems to work, I can log the data in my array to make sure it's there, but when I restart  the app, it never pulls in the plist data. 
I have been working on this for some time, and can't seem to make any progress on it.

Thanks!

Comment: You have much NSLog's so provide logs, please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your problem is the `initWithContentsOfFile:` method.

This will read an array representation that has been printed to a file. This is likely something closer to json's `[1,2,3]`than the xml plist format. What you need to do is read the data into a nsdata object and deserialize it. The process of saving data to file in a format that can be latter read is called serialization. The process of reading serialized data from a file is called deserialization.

So back to the answer: first read the data from the file

```
NSData * fileData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:dataPath];
```

Now you need to deserialize it

```
NSError * __autoreleasing error = nil; //drop the autoreleasing if non-ARC
NSPropertyListFormat format = NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0;
id array = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListWithData: fileData 
                                                     options:kCFPropertyListImmutable
                                                      format:&format 
                                                       error:&error];
if(error) {
       //don't ignore errors
}
```

you might also want to check that is actually an array and not a dictionary.